# How do you download the Portal 2 DLC: Peer Review on PC?

Tags: portal-2

How can I download the Peer Review DLC on PC? I've purchased Portal 2 in a bundle together with Portal 1. On Steam Portal 2 -> DLC there are no items to dowload. Can I play it after completing the single player part?

Answer (score 5):

It is downloaded as an update, so if you have those enabled, you should have it.

Comment: I always had the updates enabled, but i don't have DLC. Maybe I need to finish the co-op capaign as @ChapMic said.

Comment: I think you already have it on your computer, you just have to finish Co-op campaign in order to play new co-op maps or find someone who did it.

Comment: Yup, it is just an additional set of levels that opens up after completing the other areas in co-op.

Answer (score 3):

In order to play to this DLC, your friend or you have to finish the main co-op campaign.

When it is done, you will see a new pillar which will let you go to the new content of Peer Review DLC.

Comment: Are you sure you must complete the initial Co-op campaign first?